# Using object literals for my complex cases

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

Hey I was wondering if it is somehow possible to use a object literal in this case to clean up my switch statement.

```
export const getTravelInfo = () => {
  const url = window.location.href;
  switch (url as any) {
    case url.includes('trips'):
      return epicTrips;
    case url.includes('mini-trips'):
      return miniTrips;
    case url.includes('sailing-trips'):
      return sailingTrips;
    default:
      return epicTrips;
  }
};
```

This is what I have so far, I am just not sure how or even if this is possible to pass in a function and loop over the url to determine what string is present in the url and then deliver that value to the user.

```
function getTravelInfo2 () {
  const url = window.location.href;

  var travel = {
    'trips': epicTrips,
    'mini-trips': miniTrips,
    'sailing-trips': sailingTrips,
    'default': epicTrips
  };

  return travel[url];
}
```

Comment: how does your switch even work?

Comment: You pass in the current url and then if the url includes a particular string you then return what you need to return.

Comment: so, it works? I'm surprised, since all your cases are either `case: true` or `case:false` - yet your switching on a string ... is this some typescript thing that completely changes how switch works?

Comment: Yes, somewhat as you are casting url to type 'any' therefore it allows the url to be any type to switch upon not just a string.  Therefore i can identify if the url 'includes' certain values and if that is true then return what i need to return and break out the switch statement.

Comment: No, sorry, that makes absolutely no sense at all `switch("someSttring") { case true (or false):` will NEVER hit those case statements - typescript does NOT change how switch works

Comment: The original code doesn't even work, trying to make it more clever in some way seems like the wrong approach.  Why so much effort to avoid using an `if` at all costs?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to First get what I need from the URL Via

```
const url = 'http://www.test.com/trips';
firstPart = url.split('/', -1)[-1];
getTravelInfo(firstPart);

const getTravelInfo = (type) => {

var travel = {
    'trips': epicTrips,
    'mini-trips': miniTrips,
    'sailing-trips': sailingTrips,
    'default': epicTrips
  };

  return (travel[type] || travel['default']);
}
```

Much cleaner and easier to execute and understand.

Comment: This will never return `default` unless default is in the url though which didn't seem like what you were trying to accomplish.

Comment: I forgot to remove that. Edited. There will only ever be 3 different results unless we decide to add on future pages. So this works for our use case.